# Sharepoint Read list items using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I wrote a query to Read list items and a specific column value like this

```
var invoiceitemID = SPUtility.GetSPField('ID').GetValue();
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Invoices');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>'+ invoiceitemID +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'); 
var listItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(listItems);
var e = listItems.getEnumerator();
while (e.moveNext()){
     Netamount = listItems.get_item('Nettobetrag');
}
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 3):

After loading the items, the query needs to be executed and then the result should be parsed in the success handler. Example:

```
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
        '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
    );
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    ); 
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}
```

See this for more information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx

Comment: Thank you Nadeem. The caml query works for number or text fields but its not working for lookup column like this 
var Belegnummer = SPUtility.GetSPField('Belegnummer').GetValue();

var camlQuery1 = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery1.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'AttachedToInvoiceID\'/><Value Type=\'Lookup\'>'+ Belegnummer +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'); 
Something wrong with Query ?.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write (and debug) your own query, **I would recommend using the GetListItems function of the SPServices library.** If you're using JavaScript, it's super easy to implement both jQuery and the SPServices library to get some awesome & much-needed functionality.

Once you have the libraries loaded on your page (I usually put them in my master page), getting the items in a list (full or filtered) can be done with a single snippet of code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

For more info, see http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists.